# jQuery progress bar width and number animation not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to write jQuery function, that will animate progress bar's width from 0% to XY% and at the same time, it also animates number increment (also from 0% to XY%).

So far I ended up with this **Page.html**

```js
$('.progress-bar').each(function() {
    var bar = $(this);
    var value = $(this).find('.count');

    bar.prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: parseFloat(bar.attr('aria-valuenow'))
        },
        {
            duration: 3000,
            easing: 'swing',      
            step: function(now) {
                var number = parseFloat(Math.round(now * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
                bar.css({ 'width': number + '%' });
                value.text(number + '%');
            }
        });
});
```

```css
/**
 * Progress bars with centered text
 */

.progress {
  position: relative;
}

.progress span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  <script src="page.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
    <span class="count"></span>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Problem is, that the animation of the width of the progress bar is not smooth.
Number increment works fine, but it looks like the bar width animation does not keep up. Once number increment animation is done, last 20% or so of the width are animated in 200ms.

I am not really sure, what is wrong, can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That could be because the width css Attribute already has a easing applied:

```
transition: width .6s ease;
```

That is why the representation of the bar always is a bit behind.

You can fix it by adding:

```
.progress .progress-bar {
    transition: unset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is interference with the transition 
Solution:
Add this to style

```
.progress-bar {
  transition:0s all !important
}
```